# MaxValue of a periodic function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to find the maximum of a periodic function on the interval [-Pi,Pi]. What I tried is the following:

```
MyLine=Line[{{-Pi,0},{Pi,0}}];
MaxValue[Sin[x],x ∈ MyLine]
```

This gives `MaxValue::objfs` error. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyLine` is embedded in 2D space, thus for $x\in\text{MyLine}$, `x` is a 2D point and `Sin[x]` just makes no sense.

You probably meant the interval `Interval[{-Pi,Pi}]` instead, which I think should work.  But it doesn't.  I don't know why.  Maybe a bug?

```
In[27]:= MaxValue[Sin[x], x \[Element] Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]]

During evaluation of In[27]:= MaxValue::objfs: The objective function {Sin[Subscript[x, 1]]} should be scalar-valued. >>

Out[27]= MaxValue[Sin[x], x \[Element] Interval[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
```

There's an alternative, fortunately, through using a constraint:

```
MaxValue[{Sin[x], -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Great, that helps. Thank you

Comment: Technically speaking you can have a line embedded to 1D space, but your it is still a vector variable in that space. That is, `MaxValue[Sin[x], {x} \[Element] Line[{{-Pi}, {Pi}}]]`.

Comment: BTW, regarding `Interval`: this works, I'm not certain if it makes sense: `MaxValue[Sin[x], {x} \[Element] Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Line` defines a 2D region, therefore

```
MyLine = Line[{{-Pi, 0}, {Pi, 0}}];

MaxValue[First@Sin[{x1, x2}], {x1, x2} ∈ MyLine]
```

or

```
MaxValue[Sin[First@{x1, x2}], {x1, x2} ∈ MyLine]
```

or

```
MaxValue[Sin[Indexed[x, 1]], x ∈ MyLine]
```

would be the correct syntax.

But it's much simpler to use

```
MaxValue[{Sin[x], -Pi < x < Pi}, x]
```

Comment: One could also use `Max[Sin[Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]]]`.